What is the correct (rubber) adapter to avoid jacking with metal on metal?
I see on the market a slotted hockey puck, such as the one on the right in the picture below. This flat-bottom adapter is meant to fit between a hydraulic floor jack and a vehicle's pinch welds.

The adapter on the left in the picture above is meant for use with a jack stand. The bottom would line up with the cup on the jack stand, and the top would match the pinch weld.
When I hoist the vehicle with an ordinary scissor jack such as the one pictured below,

I would like to insert a rubber adapter between metal and metal. That adapter must have a slot below running parallel to the slot above.
What is the correct (rubber) adapter to avoid jacking with metal on metal?

For the left picture, I presume the slot on top goes under the cill, and the orthogonal guides underneath are supposed to fit snugly around the top of the scissor jack (to stop it falling off as the jack is raised). I've always use a bit of wood, or a folded rag, to protect the cill.

I see you edited the post after I answered what the purpose is, and also added the term "jack stand".

@WeatherVane A sheet of rubber cut from the inner tube of a bicycle tire might be constitute minimal protection, but I'm hoping there is a slightly more sizeable solution.

Yes, I figured that the left one is meant for jack stands. I don't understand how you would use the one on the left as scissor jack to pinch weld adapter.

It's just above the picture of the scissor jack. Place it on top of the jack in (almost) the orientation pictured, with the underside lips gripping the jack.

@WeatherVane I have the impression that the bottom side is just wide enough for a jack stand (as it is labeled), but not wide enough for a vehicle jack, but if you're sure that it will fit or you have first-hand experience with using it, please move your comment to be an answer.

Obviously it only fits if it fits.

@WeatherVane - Write the answer already :o)

We can't see the underside of the more rectangular pad on the left.

If it is flat, it would be suitable for a scissor jack, which has a flat top.

If it is curved it would be for jack/axle stands, because they are curved too.


Obviously, the locating lips underneath must be far enough apart in either case.
You can also get round ones which have the lips underneath.
